# allow user access to only a module in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

i want to restrict the access of a user to only one module. I have created a role for the user and checked the access permission to only that module.But when I log in as that user i can see only myaccount and logout links in the menu.Can anybody explains the access permission method is a module in a simple way. The drupal documentation is really confusing.

following is my code.

```
function products_perm() {
    return array('access products content');    
}

function products_menu() {

  $items = array();

   $items['admin/products'] = array(
    'title' => 'Products',
    'description' => 'Products',
    'page callback' => 'products_all',
    'access arguments' => array('access products content'),
    'weight' => 1,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
   );

  return $items;
}
```

I want to show only the products menu to user named Staff.

Comment: Be sure the theme set for the site is enabled, or you would see an access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the menu cache?

Any changes made using hook_menu() will require the menu structures to be rebuilt.